# multiple table good Or Bad?

Tags: database-design

I Can place data in single table ,other option is , i can use two table for the same information???
what is better using one table or two??? which will give me best performance???

table-tblschool
name
address
**Principal NAME
PRINCIPAL MOBILE
ADMIN NAME
ADMIN MOBILE**

Here in abhove table one school will have one admin and one principle ,so should i go for a different table or one table.

Comment: You should precise what is this information and what your use cases are.  
Database layout are always tricky questions, so it really depends on the usage. If the two tables work independently then by all mean separate them, if they work together, it's worth investigating.

Comment: You should give some more detail about the nature of the data. In which way are the two sets of data related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very much dependant on the data that you're putting in the table. If some of it can be repeated, then it's better to split that into a different table. Likewise if there are particular relationships.

I am, personally, of the opinion that zero-or-one relationships belong in seperate tables, also. But this isn't the case always, as some people don't mind nulls too much.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend looking at [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). It will give a little bit of perspective.

A very brief intro from wiki as follows (1NF-5NF):

- **First normal form (1NF)** - Table faithfully represents a relation and has no repeating groups
- **Second normal form (2NF)** - No non-prime attribute in the table is functionally dependent on a part (proper subset) of a candidate key
- **Third normal form (3NF)** - Every non-prime attribute is non-transitively dependent on every key of the table
- **Fourth normal form (4NF)** - Every non-trivial multivalued dependency in the table is a dependency on a superkey
- **Fifth normal form (5NF)** - Every non-trivial join dependency in the table is implied by the superkeys of the table

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a pretty vague question, there's only a vague answer at this point.
Depends on. ;) No, I'd suggest that you get into a little reading about database normalization and see where this leads you to.

Start here: [WikePedia on DB normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 1):

most of the times ,yes...depends upon requirement